# Scope with join make SQL safe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-injection, rails-activerecord

I have a scope for returning a list of projects a user has access too. Either they are on the participant list or they own the project they are listed. Query works fine except its not SQL safe. I can't figure out how to make the JOIN safe. The where clause is safe but trying the same with join doesn't work. I can't seem to find documentation or an answer here. Guessing I'm missing something basic.

```
scope :manageable_by_user, lambda { |user| 
  joins("LEFT JOIN participants ON 
         participants.project_id = projects.id 
         AND participants.user_id = #{user.id}").
  where("projects.user_id = ? OR projects.user_id IS NOT NULL",user.id)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(string)`

Comment: This works. Though the synax is a little clumsy for me. Would prefer if there was a way to do it with the ? like in the where statement. Anywho if no one comes up with anything better I'll accept this answer since it works.

Comment: hmm since you're on a scope, I think you can just use `sanitize`